# Change Android Studio Icon in the Mac OS Dock

Tags: macos, android-studio

First up, I am not sure if this is the place to ask. Since there isn't a lot of Android-Studio tags on Super User and I know that a lot of people uses Android Studio on StackOverFlow. So please correct me if I'm wrong on the comment section to save me from the down votes.

So...

I tried changing the default icon of the Android Studio IDE on my Mac and I was able to do it. The problem is when I open it, it reverts to the original icon it has, then when I quit the IDE it returns to the icon I selected. Is it possible to make it always stay with the same icon I pasted in Finder Get Info?

Here is the icon I changed it to:

[image]

But it changes to this when it is opened:

[image]

Comment: What did you do to change the default icon?

Comment: And here is a good tutorial how to change icons in Mac

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Mac-OS-X-Icons

Comment: @HarikrishnanT I did exactly the same thing as the link you gave me.

Comment: Is this really a programming related question? Wouldn't this be better on Apple.se?

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, that is why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mac OS X, there is an extra file for icons,
very commercial software always loads this file.

When you right-click the application "Android Studio",
and click on "Show Package Contents", then navigate to
Contents > Resources and replace "Android Studio.icns"
with an icon you created in a photo-editing or illustration
software (export to .icns or use a .icns icon converter).